# How to easily (auto) remove fret noise from a guitar track with Melodyne

Tags: software

Are there any tips for removing fret noise from a track using melodyne?

I'm hoping there may be some automated methods inside the software perhaps by design.

Let me know!

Comment: I don't know of anything within Melodyne itself. Izotope RX has a dedicated "de-squeaker" in its Guitar De-Noise section - https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx/features/guitar-de-noise.html